# Headphones don't work until after laptop awakens from hibernation

Tags: windows-10, audio, sound-card

I'm running Windows 10. Headphone sound only works after the PC awakes from hibernation. All drivers installed, windows update run. In Sound Playback there's no headphones, however Realtek HD Audio Manager recognizes them. How do I get it fixed?

Comment: Can you screenshot what you see in realtek?

Comment: If the machine is in hibernation, it's essentially shut off.  What do you expect to hear?